# How can space be added between the number and the section heading?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I am using a custom template and I have enabled numbering for the section headings. When the number of headings gets to 10 there is not space between the number and the heading text.

How can I control spacing in my heading style so that there is some space between number and the text?

[image: Example of heading with number and no spacing.]

I would like to have some space between the **10** and **Permissions** in the above example. This is the heading 1 style in my template. I adapted this style from the blank template and changed fonts and colors.

Comment: Move the first tab marker to the right in the formatting bar

Comment: For something more comprehensive, change the multilevel list and the style. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm#NumberedLists http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try setting Special to "Hanging" and enlarging By parameters of Paragraph options.

[image]

Comment: The correct answer is "Move the first tab marker to the right in the formatting bar"

Comment: This worked perfectly! I followed these steps to adjust the spacing: Right Click Heading 1 style > Select Modify > Select Format Paragraph > Change Special Hanging indentation from 0.30" to 0.35". This looks much better now. This change applies to all the Heading 1 instances in the document and the new position appears in the tabs stops in the ruler.

Comment: @DavidPostill "Correct" might be quite subjetive here. While your answer will only apply changes to a particular heading, this answer applies the changes to the template for all headings of the same layer, which will lead to a more consistent layout.

Comment: Actually I found this post helpful as well. In this way you can set the spacing for the same heading type across the document: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/setting-space-between-heading-number-and-heading/30561d8b-5292-4136-ad97-dcbb5a94ae04